# GridView Row Fading Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

**EDIT:**

here is what its generating at runtime after i debug the code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tabControl_gv_ctl03').show().fadeIn(8000).fadeOut(90000)
</script>
```

ere is what i am looking for...

[image]

how do i highlight the gridview control row after i am done updating with the row?

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="DataWebControlStyle">    
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRowStyle" />   
 <RowStyle CssClass="RowStyle" />    <
HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderStyle" />    
<SelectedRowStyle CssClass="SelectedRowStyle" />
</asp:GridView> 


protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
   //update....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Untested, but should be something like this:

```
protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridViewName.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(@"<script type='text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append(string.Format(@"$('#{0}').hide(200)", row.ClientId)); // hide or show here
    sb.Append(@"</script>");

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(GridViewName, this.GetType(), "showhide", sb.ToString(), false);
}
```

Comment: i try to add but dont see the effect `sb.Append(string.Format(@"$('#{0}').show().fadeIn(800).fadeOut(9000)", gvr.ClientID)); ` is there a way add different backcolor and chage it?

Comment: @Abu Hamzah - you could use the `row.CssClass = AlternatingRowStyle`. I don't see a problem with your jquery. Maybe try it out with an alert to see if your code is registering, then look for js errors. The other thing i would check is that the rows are generating unique client id's. Good Luck!

Comment: @Abu Hamzah - Hey have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444151/how-do-i-pull-the-clientid-of-an-aspbutton-inside-an-asplistview-for-use-with-j) question. You could approach this a different way and bind the client click `onrowdatabound` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridViewName.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    row.CssClass = "some class that has background-color set";
}
```

This should  (untested as well) work as long as you have not explicitly set each cells' background color.

Note: I realize you specified jQuery but since you posted a server-side function I figured this was easier.